# Mechanics of ''Sumo'' vs Conventional Deadlift

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, power

A classic strength move (called the [deadlift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZXobu7JvvE)) involves bending over a heavy bar, holding it in one's hands, and then pulling it off the floor and standing up straight.

Recently a variant called ''[sumo deadlift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQHSYDSgDn8)'' has become popular, where you place your legs much wider apart than normal and start with the back almost perpendicular to the floor, like a sumo wrestler.

This variant is controversial with some people because it is said to much easier (basically the bar does not travel as far during the lift, so the work done is reduced).

I don't think is conclusive though, because it seems to me that in the starting position of sumo with the legs placed further apart it would be harder to generate the power needed to get the bar moving off the ground.  Would it be possible to analyse the mechanics involved more carefully to show that the sumo is genuinely easier in general?  (Obviously I leave aside the differing mechanics of different people and assume a person with generic body measurements)

Comment: This is a biomechanics problem and I doubt many people here have much experience with the subject. Maybe try [biology.se].